# Remote Debugging via SSH | Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, ssh, remote-debugging

I'm programing on an embedded linux system calls BeagleBone Black. I'm using JDK vers. 1.6 to run my programms. 
At the moment i write code on my normal pc (win7), create a .jar and transfer it via FileZilla to the Linux system (arm7). Then i connect with the embedded system using Putty (ssh tunnel) and start my programm ..."java -jar [name].jar"
Now i'm searching for a way to connect Neatbeans directly to the linux system. To bypass this laborious methode. Is there a way to debugg a programm on my pc via netbeans and it will automatically run on linux? (with console output in netbeans)?
How to configurate the ide for such a task?
Or is there alternative option?

Thanks

Comment: [I wrote an answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512315/remotely-debug-unit-tests-in-netbeans-maven/37514336#37514336) Rather than re-post the answer, I'm going to try to mark this question as a duplicate of the other so that there's only one answer on the site. I'm not sure if that's the "correct" thing to do, but it seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared folder into the Beagle Bone via SSH an use it as a normal folder.
I am not sure about if you can do this on windows, but im sure that linux can!