# Remotely debug unit tests in Netbeans / Maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, netbeans

I would like to automatically launch and debug unit tests on a remote machine in a Maven project using Netbeans. All the IDE features should work, such as debugging, the output window, etc. The process has to be fully automated with a single click of "Debug Focused Test Method."

Comment: Why on a remote machine ? A unit test can be run in the IDE and of course debugged ?

Comment: @khmarbaise There could be a million reasons. For me, it is because I use JUnit "tests" to execute actual work (almost like an ipython notebook), and I want them to run on my big box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace the `mvn` command with a custom script which will perform an `rsync` and an `ssh`. Through the magic of both tools, it works *really* well. Also, it should be portable to other Maven IDEs. The current guide is for `bash`, but the same idea could be implemented in Windows with `powershell`, `groovy`, or even `cmd`. (I tried to use Nashorn, but the way to execute other commands while properly preserving all the arguments seemed broken.)

- In Netbeans directory `/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/java/maven/bin/`, rename the `mvn` script:

  - `cd /usr/local/netbeans-8.1/java/maven/bin/`
  - `sudo mv mvn mvn.orig`
- Create new `mvn` script.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  if [ -z "$REMOTE" ] ; then 
      SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname "$0")
      "$SCRIPTDIR/mvn.orig" "$@"
  else
      if [ -z "$REMOTE_BASE_DIR" ] ; then
          echo "ERROR: Please set environment variable REMOTE_BASE_DIR to the folder which contains the project directory"
          exit
      fi

      PROJECT_DIR=$(basename "$(pwd)")
      REMOTE_PROJECT_DIR=$REMOTE_BASE_DIR/$PROJECT_DIR/
      ARGS=
      for var in "$@"
      do
       ARGS="$ARGS \\\"$var\\\""
      done

      echo "Syncing project directory..."
      (set -x; rsync -aczhW --progress --delete --exclude '.git' --exclude 'target' $RSYNC_OPTS ./ "$REMOTE:\"$REMOTE_PROJECT_DIR\"")

      echo "Executing maven..."
      if [ "$REMOTE_PORT" = '${jpda.address}' ] ; then
          (set -x; ssh ${REMOTE} "cd \"$REMOTE_PROJECT_DIR\"; mvn $ARGS")
      else
          (set -x; ssh -R $REMOTE_PORT:localhost:$REMOTE_PORT ${REMOTE} "cd \"$REMOTE_PROJECT_DIR\"; mvn $ARGS")
      fi
  fi
  ```
- Configure the remote machine:

  - Either install `mvn`, or install Netbeans and put its `mvn` on the path. I chose the later, but either should be fine.
  - Configure ssh. I won't describe how to do it here. Make sure that `AllowTcpForwarding` is set to `yes` or `remote` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
- Create new Netbeans configuration that will forward all maven actions (including clean & build) to the remote machine:

  - Go into Project's properties
  - Create new Configuration
  - In "Set properties" add:

    ```
    Env.REMOTE_BASE_DIR=<directory on the server that will contain your project directory>
    Env.REMOTE=<address of remote machine>
    Env.REMOTE_PORT=${jpda.address}
    Env.RSYNC_OPTS=<optional, but could be another --exclude>
    ```

    [image: screenshot]
  - To use, select the new configuration in the drop-down menu in the toolbar, and invoke any maven goal as usual.
  - I'm still looking for a way to set up this configuration globally. If you know how to do this, please tell me!
- Alternatively, create a Custom Action that has the same properties set.
- I should mention that the debug experience works pretty well, thanks to the remote debug capabilities built into the JVM and the version/dependency tracking of Maven and the excellent Maven integration in Netbeans. I really like that you're able to easily step into the code of other projects (and it can resolve specific versions).

Comment: anyone know why my screenshot isn't displaying?

Answer (score -1):

Surefire/Failsafe plugin supports remote debugging out of the box: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

Comment: I have used this on several occasions when I needed to debug integration tests in IntelliJ IDEA and I needed Maven to execute all the pre-integration-tests steps.

Comment: The question is how to automate the process.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA this can be done by having a run configuration that executes a certain other run configuration first. If NetBeans supports similar functionality you can add breakpoints anywhere you want, and then run config that does: 1) run maven build with -Dmaven.surefire.debug; 2) connect remote debugger.
What kind of automation are you talking about? Right-clicking a test and running that test only?

Comment: You're not helping.